# Average of 4 slider values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, slider

I'm trying to get the average of 4 simple input sliders. I want to show the average value in a textfield. I'm pretty sure I need to use javascript/jquery. But i'm not very familiar with it, so I could need som help. I'm pretty sure it is very simple, but i don't know which event handler I should use etc.

I got 4 sliders just like this:

```
<div class="holder-left">
    <p>Subjektiv eller objektiv?</p>
    <input class="slider" type="range" min="1" max="5" value="3" />
    <div class="left">Subjektiv</div>
    <div class="right">Objektiv</div>
</div>
```

I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Please see below answer I hope this is your requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
$(".slider").change( function(e){
    var b=0;
    $('.slider').each(function(){
      var a=parseInt($(this).val());
      b=b+a;
    });
   var avg=b/4;
    $('#textValue').val(avg);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Result  - <input type="text" id="textValue" />
<div class="holder-left">
    <p>Subjektiv eller objektiv?</p>
    <input class="slider" type="range" min="1" max="5" value="3" />
    <div class="left">Subjektiv</div>
    <div class="right">Objektiv</div>
</div>
<div class="holder-left">
    <p>Subjektiv eller objektiv?</p>
    <input class="slider" type="range" min="1" max="5" value="4" />
    <div class="left">Subjektiv</div>
    <div class="right">Objektiv</div>
</div>
<div class="holder-left">
    <p>Subjektiv eller objektiv?</p>
    <input class="slider" type="range" min="1" max="5" value="3" />
    <div class="left">Subjektiv</div>
    <div class="right">Objektiv</div>
</div>
<div class="holder-left">
    <p>Subjektiv eller objektiv?</p>
    <input class="slider" type="range" min="1" max="5" value="5" />
    <div class="left">Subjektiv</div>
    <div class="right">Objektiv</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's very close to what I'm looking for, then I just need to show the value in a textfield instead of alerting the value. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry. I just need to delete the alert part :)

Comment: Done please see on top I have a text box now on top you can remove alert

Comment: Is it working correct for you or do you want me to update anything else?

Comment: It works when I refresh the page, but I want it to update the textfield live? Think I need to listen for some kind of change/event?

Comment: On what event you want to update value? actually this code is working on page load right now

Comment: Yeah it works on page load :) But I dont know which event are the right one? When the slider changes value, the textfield with the average value needs to change simultaneously.

Comment: Done, please check now on changing slider it's updating value

Comment: Great, enjoy Jquery :)